# change colour and weight of a var in html5 using javascript or css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this var in a javascript file:

```
var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
```

'nombre' is in a html file:

```
Nombre: <input type="text" name="name_control" id="nombre" autofocus required />
```

Then I add this var to a list but I want to change the colour or the size of the text to add it into the list in other colour.
Is this possible?
Thanks.

Edit:
Then I do this.
the problem is that when I add nombre to the list, nombre is a simple text (dark and small) and I want to add nombre (node.appendChild(textnode)) in colour red and bigger.

```
var node = document.createElement("LI"); 
var textnode = document.createTextNode(nombre+" ");
node.appendChild(textnode);
```

Comment: Can you give more specifics? You want to change the style (text color and size) of the input element or the label or something else? What is this list you are referring to?

Comment: What list? Have you any experience with CSS? Changing the colour of most things is quite trivial.

Comment: @mason81 when I save the text I write in to the var, I want to change the text style that I have stored in this var

Comment: Could you give an example? Like: "If I enter 'blue' in the nombre input box, I want to change the style of the text box to 'blue'" It's not very clear what you're actually trying to do. perhaps edit your question with more of your code to give some more context as to what you have and better explain what you are trying to it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a `span` instead

```
    var span= document.createElement('span');
     span.innerHTML = nombre+" ";
    //set the color and font weight before appending to dom
    span.style.color = "red";
    span.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    span.style.fontSize  = "large";
```

Comment: Cannot set property 'fontWeight' of undefined the same with color and fontsize

Comment: @Manumarigle try this

Comment: where I have to create the span?

Comment: @Manumarigle use a span instead of text node , text nodes themselves don't have any style

Comment: excellent!! thanks so much.

Comment: Why use a span when there's a perfectly serviceable, brand new, list item?

Comment: @Quentin OP originally didn't create `li`